# Show 'space' character via listchars only for leading spaces

Tags: vim, vi

Is it possible in Vim to have my editor (when editing `.c` and `.h` files), show via `listchars`, a special character only for **leading** space characters?

I found a separate post that noted, as of version 7.4, Vim now supports highlighting all space characters via `listchars`. Here's my current `listchars` variable:

```
set list listchars=tab:>-,trail:.,extends:>,precedes:<,space:.
```

And here is a render of how it appears on my screen:

[image: This it appear on my screen]

However, I would like it to appear like so (below), where only **leading** spaces are rendered via `listchars`, and spaces occurring after indentation-related spaces are not rendered. ie:

[image: The desired behaviour]

Is there a simple way to accomplish this, either via color scheme or `.vimrc` changes?

---

Image diff in case the difference isn't obvious due to low contrast:

[image: Image diff in case the difference isn't obvious due to low contrast]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that `linechars` will help you, but this highlight might help:

```
highlight WhiteSpaceBol guibg=lightgreen
match WhiteSpaceBol /^ \+/
```

Change the color scheme for whatever you like best.

If you insist on having the fancy `·` you can get them with a bit of a hack:

```
set listchars=space:·
highlight WhiteSpaceBol guifg=blue
highlight WhiteSpaceMol guifg=white
match WhiteSpaceMol / /
2match WhiteSpaceBol /^ \+/
```

Now, only the starting `·` are visible! (change the `white` for whatever color you use as background and `blue` with the color of your choice).

NOTE: If you use the console Vim, replace (or add) `guibg` with `ctermbg` and the proper colors.

Comment: Having some issues with this. Do all of the above go into `.vimrc`?

Comment: Yes, I've but those in `.vimrc` (version 8.0) and it worked with `gvim`. With the `vim` console you should use `ctermbg` instead of `guibg`.

Comment: @DevNull: Can you be more specific? What are your issues?

Comment: I put the entire list (all 7 lines above) in my VIMRC, but the non-leading `space` characters are still visible, using the same light-grey color as "leading" `space` characters (ie: rendered output on-screen is the same before-and-after adding the 7 lines of code you posted). Maybe my existing color scheme settings are interfering with it.

Comment: @DevNull Are you using console Vim or Gvim?

Comment: Console vim built from Git source, plus I enabled `xterm_clipboard` support.

Comment: @DevNull And did you try with `ctermbg`?

Comment: Yep. Tried with `ctermbg`, no effect. I removed the following entry from my custom color scheme, but now, even with the above code, all spaces are bright blue. `hi SpecialKey guifg=#1c1c1c        ctermfg=236
`.

Comment: Nice!  Note that you have to do this in your vimrc _after_ setting the colorscheme.  Otherwise, the colorscheme will undo any custom highlighting